# JS\Node Reduce group by multiple properties and summarize JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, reduce

I have following data that i'm trying to group summarize and add back to related object.

```
{
  "Schedule": [
    {
      "AppointmentId": 123456,
      "Start": "2021-11-02T09:00:00.000Z",
      "Location": 87925,
      "InsuranceName": "Geico",
      "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
      "AppointmentName": "Online",
      "LocalDate": "11/02/2021",
      "LocalTime": "9:00 AM",
      "TimeOfDay": "AM"
    },
    {
      "AppointmentId": 123457,
      "Start": "2021-11-03T10:00:00.000Z",
      "Location": 87925,
      "InsuranceName": "Farmers",
      "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
      "AppointmentName": "InPerson",
      "LocalDate": "11/03/2021",
      "LocalTime": "10:00 AM",
      "TimeOfDay": "AM"
    },
    {
      "AppointmentId": 123458,
      "Start": "2021-11-03T11:00:00.000Z",
      "Location": 87925,
      "InsuranceName": "Farmers",
      "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
      "AppointmentName": "InPerson",
      "LocalDate": "11/03/2021",
      "LocalTime": "11:00 AM",
      "TimeOfDay": "AM"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the final result to look like the following:

```
{
    "Schedule": [
      {
        "AppointmentId": 123456,
        "Start": "2021-11-02T09:00:00.000Z",
        "Location": 87925,
        "InsuranceName": "Geico",
        "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
        "AppointmentName": "Online",
        "LocalDate": "11/02/2021",
        "LocalTime": "9:00 AM",
        "TimeOfDay": "AM",
        "Summary": {
            "InsuranceName": {
                "Total": 1,
                "Geico": 1                
            },
            "InsuranceFinancialClass": {
                "Total": 1,
                "Commercial": 1
            },
            "AppointmentName": {
                "Total": 1,
                "Online": 1,
                "InPerson": 1        
            },
            "LocalDate": {
                "Total": 1,
                "11/02/2021": 1,                
            }
        }        
      },
      {
        "AppointmentId": 123457,
        "Start": "2021-11-03T10:00:00.000Z",
        "Location": 87925,
        "InsuranceName": "Farmers",
        "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
        "AppointmentName": "InPerson",
        "LocalDate": "11/03/2021",
        "LocalTime": "10:00 AM",
        "TimeOfDay": "AM",
        "Summary": {
            "InsuranceName": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "Farmers": 2
            },
            "InsuranceFinancialClass": {
                "Total": 2,
                "Commercial": 2
            },
            "AppointmentName": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "InPerson": 2
            },
            "LocalDate": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "11/03/2021": 2
            }
        }
      }
      {
        "AppointmentId": 123458,
        "Start": "2021-11-03T11:00:00.000Z",
        "Location": 87925,
        "InsuranceName": "Farmers",
        "InsuranceFinancialClass": "Commercial",
        "AppointmentName": "InPerson",
        "LocalDate": "11/03/2021",
        "LocalTime": "11:00 AM",
        "TimeOfDay": "AM",
        "Summary": {
            "InsuranceName": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "Farmers": 2
            },
            "InsuranceFinancialClass": {
                "Total": 2,
                "Commercial": 2
            },
            "AppointmentName": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "InPerson": 2
            },
            "LocalDate": {
                "Total": 2,                
                "11/03/2021": 2
            }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have following JS code that:

```
const props = ['LocalDate', 'AppointmentName', 'InsuranceFinancialClass', 'InsuranceName'];

const result = JSONData.reduce((r, e) => {
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (props.includes(k)) {
        if (!r[k]) r[k] = {};
        r[k].Total = (r[k].Total || 0) + 1;
        r[k][v] = (r[k][v] || 0) + 1;
      }
    });
    return r;
  }, {});
```

```
{
    "Schedule": {
        "InsuranceName": {
            "Total": 3,
            "Geico": 1,
            "Farmers": 2
        },
        "InsuranceFinancialClass": {
            "Total": 3,
            "Commercial": 3
        },
        "AppointmentName": {
            "Total": 3,
            "Online": 1,
            "InPerson": 2       
        },
        "LocalDate": {
            "Total": 3,
            "11/02/2021": 1,
            "11/03/2021": 2
        }
    }
}
```

How should the code be written produce desired result?

The summary object should be aggregate by date and appended to original object that matches the date.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). _"I have following JSON object..."_ which won't be the content of `JSONData` because that's an array of objects (otherwise `.reduce()` would throw an error) and not only an object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a solution but not sure if it's efficient.

```
  const props = ['LocalDate', 'AppointmentName', 'InsuranceFinancialClass', 'InsuranceName'];
  const groupedByDateSummary = filteredByPatientAppointment.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (!r[e.LocalDate]) r[e.LocalDate] = {};
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (props.includes(k)) {
        if (!r[e.LocalDate][k]) r[e.LocalDate][k] = {};
        r[e.LocalDate][k].Total = (r[e.LocalDate][k].Total || 0) + 1;
        r[e.LocalDate][k][v] = (r[e.LocalDate][k][v] || 0) + 1;
      }
    });
    return r;
  }, {});

  const slotObjWithSummary = _.each(filteredByPatientAppointment, (summary) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(groupedByDateSummary)) {
      if (key === summary.LocalDate) {
        summary.Summary = value;
      }
    }
    return summary;
  });
```